# Getting local group from mapped drives c#

Tags: c#, directory, active-directory, nas

We are facing on issue with Giving folder access to mapped path from c#. We have one map drive and it's mapped using code. It's working fine, and we try to give the access using below code.

```
DirectorySecurity dirSec = Directory.GetAccessControl(clientFolder);
dirSec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(@"Local group Name", FileSystemRights.Modify, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
```

Getting error while adding the AddAccessRule.

**Error:**

```
Some or all identity references could not be translated.
```

**Trace:**

```
 at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Type targetType, Boolean forceSuccess)
   at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(Type targetType)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.CommonObjectSecurity.ModifyAccess(AccessControlModification modification, AccessRule rule, Boolean& modified)
   at System.Security.AccessControl.CommonObjectSecurity.AddAccessRule(AccessRule rule)
```

Note: We are using AD service account to map the NAS and we are trying to add local group from parent computer. This group not accessible by AD and it's same domain.

Please give me any idea, give the access for Local service account to NAS.

Comment: Looks like some info are missing, indeed the correct account to be used for a service which involve network usage is network service instead of local service. However I saw many times legacy application that in order to overcome similar issues requires to create an AD user, i.e. ServiceMyProgramName and set that in the service logon properties so it can be allowed trough standard security tools to manage all what you need in order to assign permission or create folders.

Comment: @P.Lion Need to give the access permission for existing folder for Local group.

Comment: It's not working as we expected: please can you specify if
1) Is the AddAccessRule returning any error? 
2) After the execution of AddAccessRule if you check security for the clientFolder can you see the "Local group Name" among the permission list?
3) does it work as read?
4) this shared folder is including everyone read and write within sharing level permission ? I means not the file one, but the permission that are set at sharing/smb service level on the server or NAS; 
In fact even if you give write to "LocalGroup" at file level but the sharing states that "everyone" has read

Comment: @P.Lion Updated question above, Please have a look

Comment: That error can be due to an incorrect group referring, be sure you are providing the realm properly, it should be including the servername, i.e. "SVRNAS01\LocalGroup"
Eventually try to see if a domain and a builtin valid group are accepted without error, preferrably on a new test subfolder inside the clientfolder.
i.e. "DOMAINNAME\DomainGroup", "BUILTIN\Administrators", "BUILTIN\Users"

Comment: Thanks @P.Lion, specified same group name what we used manually. Manually we can add it and unable to proceed with programmatically.

Comment: Considering that manually there is no way you can operate as Local Service, likely the NAS is not allowing to the Local Service to change security on folders, so you need either to figure out how to allow manually "NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE" to do it or preferably, to create a Domain User allowed to do that and make your service impersonating it.

Comment: Also be aware that builtin username can change according to the server language, you can find further details about naming at the bottom of this page. To be 100% sure of the account your service is working with you can create an empty text file on windows temp or any folder set for "Everyone" Full control permission and check the file properties/creator

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-windows-service-accounts-and-permissions?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We added the group manually to one folder and we are storing the IdentityReference.Value into one variable. Then we easily got the IdentityReference,Using this we added programmatic to other folders. Below code used to get the IdentityReference

```
        public IdentityReference getReference(string NameOfDirectory)
        {
            DirectorySecurity dirSec = Directory.GetAccessControl(NameOfDirectory);
            AuthorizationRuleCollection accessRules;
            IdentityReference identity = null;
            accessRules = dirSec.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));
            foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in accessRules)
            {
                if (identity == null)
                {
                    if (rule.IdentityReference.Value != null && rule.IdentityReference.Value.Equals(Constants.securityId))
                    {
                        dirSec.RemoveAccessRuleSpecific(rule);
                        identity = rule.IdentityReference;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return identity;
        }
```